# How to troubleshoot Yahoo mail Android app that shows empty error pop-up on login attempt

Tags: email, yahoo-mail

As part of migrating to a new Pixel 7 phone and accessing email for her work, my spouse installed the Yahoo Mail app, which shows three options, login with Yahoo, login with Google, and create new account.

Tapping any of those options shows this empty pop-up message with a single button, “OK”, which returns to that same screen of three options. This app lacks any other starting point for logging in.

[image: Yahoo mail empty error]

She’s already able to access her Yahoo Mail account from a browser tab on the same Pixel 7 device connected to the same Wifi network, so the issue appears specific to Yahoo’s app itself.

Search results for an empty error message (so far) fail to provide anything useful via Google or Yahoo’s mail help. Our best guess is that changing devices led to this situation.

How would you troubleshoot this kind of issue that lacks a clear error in-app message?

Comment: Wild guess: is the Dark theme enabled, or otherwise a color-modifying app/feature used?

Comment: Thanks, we checked and dark/adaptive modes all appear disabled. We also just tried a long-press to select and copy potential white-on-white text without success on that Yahoo Mail app alert box.

Comment: How about uninstall and reinstall

Comment: Also may like to try [SD maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) to clean the system and wipe the uninstall properly. There is also a later version of the app more suitable for later versions of Android. You can give them a shot

Comment: We did try uninstall and reinstall a few times, with no change in behavior. While she replaced the device itself, it will be interesting to see if others hit this issue.